# Multi-DoF Joint Planning

Tags: ros, quadcopter, ompl, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The arm_navigation documentation explains how to specify multi DoF joints in the planning description yaml file, eg the "joint" between base_link and the world. Is it possible to motion plan for these, e.g. to create a motion plan for base_link relative to the world, and if so how? Using the standalone OMPL app its possible to plan for rigid bodies in 3D and I'd like to do something similar in ROS.

Thanks!

James

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30044/multi-dof-joint-planning/) by [jwrobbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1711/jwrobbo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 258 on 2012-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello James,

Do you have your own collision checker for the quad rotor? Or a way to decide whether a particular pose it may attain is valid?
If so, I recommend using OMPL directly. You just need to plan in SE3, so just define an SE3StateSpace, and define the bounds for your space. You can then follow tutorials on http://ompl.info about how to set the StateValidityChecker and how to actually compute (optionally simplify) the plans.
Please reply if you have any further questions!

Ioan

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2012-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1